# Definition of Suslin space

Tags: general-topology, polish-spaces

**Definition 1** (wikipedia) A Suslin space is the image of a Polish space under a continuous mapping.

**Definition 2** (Morris, Topology without Tears) A topological space (X, τ ) is said to be a Souslin space (or Suslin space) if it is Hausdorff and a continuous image of a Polish space.

> Are these two definition equivalent? That is, can we prove (a) $f:X\to Y$ continuous, (b) $X$ Polish, imply $Y$ Hausdorff?

Note: Here we have two further definitions?!? [Can someone reconcile the two definition of Suslin's condition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1821432)

Comment: Suslin (or Souslin, German or French transliteration of the Russian name from Cyrillic; he wrote papers in both those languages and the name is written differently in accordance with the language of the paper) did more things, so some unrelated properties are named after him.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is Polish and $Y$ is $X$ with indiscrete topology then identity map is a continuous map from $X$ onto $Y$. Hence it is not true that a continuous image of a Polish space is Hausdorff.

Comment: Note. some authors make a blanket assumption that all topological spaces they consider are Hausdorff. Souslin spaces are certainly supposed to be Hausdorff, even if that is not mentioned explicitly.

Comment: Almost certainly Suslin would have assumed Hausdorff by default, the most popular standard reference for general topology in his days was Hausdorff's Mengenlehre which assumes it as an axiom for a topological space.